# Cloud Functions deployment requires the pay-as-you-go (Blaze) billing plan

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

After i upgraded to node 10, i am facing this error when deploy my functions

```
 Cloud Functions deployment requires the pay-as-you-go (Blaze) billing plan.
```

Is downgrading node will solve the problem at least temporarily, Is there a way to solve the problem without downgrading??

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Change the following in `functions/package.json`:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "8"
}
```

It should solve the problem (for now), the official [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions).

TL;DR:

> - Node.js 10. This runtime requires the Blaze pay-as-you-go billing plan. This plan provides generous amounts of invocations, compute time, and internet traffic free of charge. See Cloud Functions pricing.
> - Node.js 8 (deprecated as of June 8, 2020). Deployment of Node.js 8 functions will no longer be allowed after February 15, 2020. Then, executions of already-deployed **Node.js 8 functions will stop after March 15, 2021**. If you have deployed functions to the Node.js 8 runtime, you're recommended to upgrade to the Node.js 10 runtime.

Comment: this worked thank you, now if i need to upgrade to node 10 and use the free offer i should show them my credit card details??

Comment: yes, you have to, but you can set limits on your gcp account and have alerts to make sure you know when you hitting your limits

Comment: As of today, July 16, 2020. Deployment of a newer project with functions in Node.js 8 is happening with the above-mentioned deprecation warning. So, developers, who are willing to deploy a new project with functions without moving to the Blaze plan can still do by Switching node version from 10 to 8. I will try updating it here once firebase stops allowing the newer projects with functions to be deployed without a Blaze plan.

Comment: I'm trying to find the file that has this node version but i can't find it can you please tell me how to find it?

Comment: @OnurBalli your package.json file, take a look at this if you need to get started https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Comment: wow!! Firebase has no more free quota :( without any card. Might use on Node 8 at the momemt

Comment: The Node.js 8 runtime is deprecated and will be decommissioned on 2021-03-15. For more information, see: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#functions-runtime

Comment: actually this might not help if you are trying to use e.g. scheduled cloud functions (pubsub api)

Comment: It is not working for me anymore. I tried to deploy targeting nodejs 8 and it shows a message mentioning the billing account (**The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent**). I've added my credit card and keep getting the same message.

Comment: @AlitonOliveira contact support